# How do I pass an argument into a dynamic page in jquery mobile(within a function)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this function:

```
var getData = function () {

    for(var i = 0, j = localStorage.length; i < j; i ++) {
        var newKey = localStorage.key(i);
        var newValue = localStorage.getItem(newKey);    
        var newObj = JSON.parse(newValue);
        var ulListView = $('#container').append('<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="minus" data-split-theme="c" data-inset="true" id="ulOrigin'+i+'"></ul>');
        var objPage = $(newObj[1].value).trigger('create'); //Create an obj. of type page
        var strnDynPage = JSON.stringify(objPage.selector); //Extract the selector and convert it into a string to use for the id       

        var insideLi = $('#ulOrigin'+i).append('<li><a href="#'+objPage.selector+'"><img src="images/'+newObj[0].value+'.png"><h2>'+newObj[1].value+'</h2><p>'+newObj[0].value+'</p></a><a href = "#deleteObject" data-rel = "popup" data-position-to = "window" data-transition = "pop">Delete Entry</a></li>');       
        //var dynPage = $('<div data-role = "page" id = "'+newObj[1].value+'"><div data-role = "header"></div><div data-role = "content"></div><div data-role = "footer"></div>"</div>');
        console.log(typeof objPage.selector);

    }


};
```

And in this function I create dynamic lists with some click-able items. I want to be able to assign a dynamic page for every list.

**Things I've tried:**

In the function I create a dynamic page, get the .selector (which returns a string value) and assign it to the a href. of the list. I do not get any errors, but the page does not open. Any thoughts on this matter? Thanks much.

Comment: let us see some code or a jsfiddle

Comment: dont just say what you have tried.. show it.

Comment: I do not like the space between the i and the ++. but why not use jQuery? `$.each(localStorage,function (key, item) {...}`

Comment: Sorry, guys I've tried to add it to jsFiddle but because this is just a part of a web CMS (with a CRUD) I can't make jsFiddle work with me. If I figure out a way to trim it, I'll edit. However, my question is very specific to the code listed above. If you guys can see a logical error I would be more than appreciative.

Comment: Can you, at least, add to you question an output of a variable newObj? I would like to see page content store in it. Also, trigger('create') will not be enough because it styles only content. You should use trigger('pagecreate') instead. One more thing, if you want, lets continue this discussion over the mail.

Comment: Gajotres, I sent you an email at your gmail.com account. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is jquery mobile then

```
<a href="#'+objPage.selector+'">
```

we need to see what

```
objPage.selector
```

is returning, add your generated html to the question

Comment: Op says this is using jquery, either way there must be something wrong with the output

Comment: Theres probably something wrong with an output but your answer is not correct.

Comment: @Gajotres that depends on if it's jquery mobile or not

Comment: Right, this is jQuery Mobile. I guess I should edit the first post.